# VBoxLinuxAddition configuration in Linux VM for shared folder in host machine

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have installed VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.8.iso under /mnt.

I am running `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` in `/mnt` and install fails with:

```
[root@dev1 mnt]# tail -f /var/log/vboxadd-install.log
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:97: *** Error: unable to find the 
sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run 
Make again.  Stop.

Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

To fix the Kernel path, I gave `[root@dev1 kernels]# KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels` before running `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`. I am still receiving the same error after this. What am I missing?

```
[root@dev1 mnt]# cd /usr/src/kernels
[root@dev1 kernels]# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root root 4096 Jul 22 17:00 4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64+debug



[root@dev1 4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64+debug]# which make
/usr/bin/make
[root@dev1 4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64+debug]# which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Also downloading from repo does not work:

```
[root@dev1 mnt]# dnf update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:33:54 ago on Sun Jul 23 08:43:29 2017.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

[root@dev1 mnt]# dnf install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11 
virtualbox-guest-utils
Last metadata expiration check: 0:34:06 ago on Sun Jul 23 08:43:29 2017.
No package virtualbox-guest-dkms available.
No package virtualbox-guest-x11 available.
No package virtualbox-guest-utils available.
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normally try to install guest-additions from the guest-repositories instead of the CD (enable your `contrib`-repositories in the guest first).**

Nevertheless, for Fedora maybe compiling is necessary:

1. Update the fedora-guest:

   ```
   sudo dnf update && sudo dnf upgrade
   ```
2. Install the required kernel- and header-modules:

   ```
   sudo dnf install dkms gcc kernel-devel kernel-headers
   ```
3. Reboot Fedora-guest

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```
4. When fresh booted, "insert" the guest-additions-ISO to the Fedora-guest and run it's `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`-file
5. Insert your password and compilation/installation should begin.
6. When compiling is done, reboot the guest as above. It should work now!

---

Don't forget to add your virtualbox guest-username to the group `vboxsf`, otherwise (as a guest) you don't have the permission to write into that shared folder:

```
sudo adduser username vboxsf
```

---

Does this work?

Comment: Also downloading from repo does not work(please see my revised issue description, it looks like comment section does not take formatted code snippets

Comment: I changed my description. Does it work now?

Comment: All I needed is `sudo dnf install dkms gcc kernel-devel kernel-headers` now I can see the shared folder from my host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the `kernel-devel` and `kernel-headers` packages. They contain the source and include files needed for VirtualBox.